# Why does print of S4 class call `show` without namespacing it?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have a package `shinyjs` with a function called `show`.  Today a user reported to me that this introduces problems when using S4 objects because "print"-ing an S4 object uses the `show` method, which is masked by my package when it's attached.

Example:

```
library(shinyjs)
setClass("testS4Object",
         representation(
           ID = "numeric",
           Name = "character"
         ),
         prototype(
           ID = NA_real_,
           Name = NA_character_
         )
)
x = new("testS4Object")
x
```

There's an error because when we print the value of `x`, it seems to call `show` under the scenes, but it's using `shinyjs::show` instead of `methods::show`.  By printing `methods::show(x)` explicitly, the problem goes away.  But I'm a bit confused as to why by default the S4 printing system calls `show` without namespacing it - isn't it dangerous and not really my package's fault that this bug is happening?

It is considered a very bad idea to have a function with the same name as a function in `methods`? My thinking is that the S4 system should know to call their own `show` function or an inherited S4 `show` function.

**EDIT:** I asked Hadley what he thinks and he seems to also think this might be a bug in R, I emailed r-devel to get their opinion

Comment: Is `show` intended to be used by clients? If not, would *not* exporting it (e.g. in your `NAMESPACE` file) affect the functionality of other functions in your package?

Comment: It is intended to be used. It's the most popular function in the package.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to rename in then.

Comment: So am I to understand that defining a `show` method is just as dangerous as defining a `print` method?  This is intended behaviour of printing S4?

Comment: I believe that's correct. I'm not completely sure about this, but I think the issue stems mainly from the fact that `methods` is loaded automatically, so your exported `show` function is being found first on R's search path. But I'm semi-speculating here, so it's probably best to hold off on making any changes until someone can give you a better answer. Good question though.

Comment: thanks, will wait to hopefully see more answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was reported to the R core team and was fixed on 2015-07-20 in SVN commit # 68702.  [Here is the fix](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/38ea40dcd0353af16d35296ee621338c49ae48c9)

The fix will be available in R 3.3.0