# Printing a list calls shinyjs in R

Tags: r, shinyjs

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127056/why-does-print-of-s4-class-call-show-without-namespacing-it) link shinyjs overwrites the show function.
It was mentioned that this was solved in R3.3.0, but I still have this issue.

```
DESeqdata <- list(DESeq = dds, colData = colData, Prepared_reads = Prepared_reads)
print(DES)
```

> $DESeq
>
> Error: shinyjs: could not find the Shiny session object. This
>   usually happens when a shinyjs function is called from a context that
>   wasn't set up by a Shiny session.

```
class(DES)
```

> [1] "list"

Running the components individually `DES[[1]]` works, but `print(DES[[1]])` does not. Probably because `DES[[1]]` is no longer a list..?

Do I need to update shinyjs or R or anything?

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
 [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
[12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics 
[5] grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shinyjs_0.9               
 [2] reshape_0.8.6             
 [3] ggplot2_2.2.1             
 [4] shinyBS_0.61              
 [5] digest_0.6.12             
 [6] SCAN.UPC_2.16.0           
 [7] sva_3.22.0                
 [8] genefilter_1.56.0         
 [9] mgcv_1.8-16               
[10] nlme_3.1-131              
[11] foreach_1.4.3             
[12] affyio_1.44.0             
[13] affy_1.52.0               
[14] GEOquery_2.40.0           
[15] oligo_1.38.0              
[16] Biostrings_2.42.1         
[17] XVector_0.14.0            
[18] oligoClasses_1.36.0       
[19] gplots_3.0.1              
[20] fpc_2.1-10                
[21] DESeq2_1.14.1             
[22] SummarizedExperiment_1.4.0
[23] Biobase_2.34.0            
[24] GenomicRanges_1.26.3      
[25] GenomeInfoDb_1.10.3       
[26] IRanges_2.8.1             
[27] S4Vectors_0.12.1          
[28] BiocGenerics_0.20.0       
[29] data.table_1.10.4         
[30] DT_0.2                    
[31] shiny_1.0.0               
[32] BiocInstaller_1.24.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6         
 [2] RColorBrewer_1.1-2   
 [3] httr_1.2.1           
 [4] prabclus_2.2-6       
 [5] tools_3.3.3          
 [6] backports_1.0.5      
 [7] R6_2.2.0             
 [8] rpart_4.1-10         
 [9] KernSmooth_2.23-15   
[10] Hmisc_4.0-2          
[11] DBI_0.6              
[12] lazyeval_0.2.0       
[13] colorspace_1.3-2     
[14] trimcluster_0.1-2    
[15] nnet_7.3-12          
[16] gridExtra_2.2.1      
[17] bit_1.1-12           
[18] preprocessCore_1.36.0
[19] htmlTable_1.9        
[20] diptest_0.75-7       
[21] caTools_1.17.1       
[22] scales_0.4.1         
[23] checkmate_1.8.2      
[24] DEoptimR_1.0-8       
[25] mvtnorm_1.0-6        
[26] robustbase_0.92-7    
[27] stringr_1.2.0        
[28] foreign_0.8-67       
[29] base64enc_0.1-3      
[30] htmltools_0.3.5      
[31] htmlwidgets_0.8      
[32] RSQLite_1.1-2        
[33] mclust_5.2.2         
[34] BiocParallel_1.8.1   
[35] gtools_3.5.0         
[36] acepack_1.4.1        
[37] RCurl_1.95-4.8       
[38] magrittr_1.5         
[39] modeltools_0.2-21    
[40] Formula_1.2-1        
[41] Matrix_1.2-8         
[42] Rcpp_0.12.9          
[43] munsell_0.4.3        
[44] stringi_1.1.2        
[45] MASS_7.3-44          
[46] zlibbioc_1.20.0      
[47] flexmix_2.3-13       
[48] plyr_1.8.4           
[49] grid_3.3.3           
[50] affxparser_1.46.0    
[51] gdata_2.17.0         
[52] miniUI_0.1.1         
[53] lattice_0.20-34      
[54] splines_3.3.3        
[55] annotate_1.52.1      
[56] locfit_1.5-9.1       
[57] knitr_1.15.1         
[58] geneplotter_1.52.0   
[59] codetools_0.2-15     
[60] XML_3.98-1.1         
[61] latticeExtra_0.6-28  
[62] httpuv_1.3.3         
[63] gtable_0.2.0         
[64] kernlab_0.9-25       
[65] assertthat_0.1       
[66] mime_0.5             
[67] xtable_1.8-2         
[68] ff_2.2-13            
[69] class_7.3-14         
[70] survival_2.40-1      
[71] tibble_1.2           
[72] iterators_1.0.8      
[73] AnnotationDbi_1.36.2 
[74] memoise_1.0.0        
[75] cluster_2.0.5
```

Comment: Same issue, running R 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your situation.  But I needed to access an list after closing a shiny app.  I was able to access the list after running:

```
unloadNamespace('shinyjs')
```